# what is the significance of a ram in the unknown trespass offering sacrifice? Why not a lamb?

Tags: sin, korban, parashat-vayikra

Leviticus 5 gives instructions for offering a lamb for a known sin of trespass, but a ram for unknowingly trespassing against the Lord. What is the difference in the types of sacrifice?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Joy! Perhaps you'd like to take a look at our [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). Hope to see you around.

Comment: Are you referring to verses 14-19?

Answer (score 1):

A classic explanation is, because when a man *knows* that he faulted, he would regret more than a man that just *doubts*. So in case of a known sin, the qorban is just a lamb, instead of a ram for a "not-sure" case.

Comment: Citing who says this explanation would add value to your post.

Answer (score 1):

In *Guide for the Perplexed* 3:26 [Rambam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides) writes:

> You ask why must a lamb be sacrificed and not a ram? but the same
>   question would be asked, why a ram had been commanded instead of a
>   lamb, so long as one particular kind is required. The same is to be
>   said as to the question why were seven lambs sacrificed and not eight;
>   the same question might have been asked if there were eight, ten, or
>   twenty lambs, so long as some definite number of lambs were
>   sacrificed. It is almost similar to the nature of a thing which can
>   receive different forms, but actually receives one of them. We must
>   not ask why it has this form and not another which is likewise
>   possible, because we should have to ask the same question if instead
>   of its actual form the thing had any of the other possible forms. Note
>   this, and understand it. ([Friedlander translation](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp162.htm))

Answer (score 0):

The lamb (in this case) is a [sin-offering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sin_offering). Its brought for a number of reasons outlined in chapter 4 and part of chapter 5.

The ram (in this case) is a [guilt-offering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guilt_offering). There are five cases when the guilt-offering is brought. In chapter 5, three of the cases are discusses.

Comment: It sounds like part of the question is *why* the former is a chatas and the latter is an asham.